# ASE (Python module) and ABINIT Calculator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in ASE (a Python package) and trying to use ABINIT (DFT code) calculator from ASE. MY OS is UBUNTU. I have downloaded ABINIT binary code and extract it in the /home/work/abinit-5.4.3 and try to export following variables

```
export ABINIT_SCRIPT=/home/work/abinit.py
export ABINIT_PP_PATH=/home/work/abinit-5.3.4/tests/Psps_for_test
```

And in the abinit.py which is /home/work/ in I have

```
import os
abinit = '/home/work/abinit-5.3.4'
exitcode = os.system('%s < %s.files > %s.log' % (abinit, label, label))
```

However when I try to run simple Si bulk simulation I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_ASE_Abinit.py", line 21, in <module>
    e = bulk.get_potential_energy()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ase/atoms.py", line 548, in get_potential_energy
    return self._calc.get_potential_energy(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ase/calculators/abinit.py", line 204, in get_potential_energy
    self.update(atoms)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ase/calculators/abinit.py", line 103, in update
    self.initialize(atoms)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ase/calculators/abinit.py", line 199, in initialize
    raise RuntimeError('No pseudopotential for %s!' % symbol)
RuntimeError: No pseudopotential for Si!
```

It seems that it couldn't find the pseudo-potential despite I have it in the folder, I also tried for aluminum and get the same error.

----------- Edit -------------------------------------

And my ASE-Python code is:

```
from ase import *
from ase.calculators.abinit import Abinit

a0 = 5.43
bulk = Atoms('Si2', [(0, 0, 0),
                     (0.25, 0.25, 0.25)],
             pbc=True)
b = a0 / 2
bulk.set_cell([(0, b, b),
               (b, 0, b),
               (b, b, 0)], scale_atoms=True)

calc = Abinit(label='Si',
              nbands=8,
              xc='PBE',
              ecut=50 * Ry,
              mix=0.01,
              kpts=[10, 10, 10])

bulk.set_calculator(calc)
e = bulk.get_potential_energy()
```

Comment: `Test_ASE_Abinit.py` is your code? You probably need to show it in order to get help.